# Android SharedPreference lifecycle

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application I have a few SharedPreference values. The mode is PRIVATE (0), so these preferences are in bounds of application. What I'm interested in, is are they removed after de-installation of the application? Or they still stay somewhere in the system until clear() will be called? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deinstalation shall remove shared preferences.   APK update preserves them

Answer (score 2):

SharedPreferences count as your application data, which is **deleted** when the app is uninstalled.
I don't think you can force the device to keep them.

Comment: The adb uninstall command includes a flag (I think its -K) to keep shared preferences, which is ok for development, but you can't expect end users to know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreference will be deleted only:

1. When the user uninstalls the app.
2. When the user clears the app data through Settings > Apps.